# Which database server prisma based on?

Tags: graphql, prisma

I would like to know about Prisma more detail.

First of all, I would like to know what database Prisma based on.

Is it RDBMS or Nosql?

Also, this command create new database server:

```
prima deploy
```

I would like to now if this database is based on RDBMS, or NoSql.

And how can I access to this database without graphql, such as phpmyadmin or mongobooster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generally good resource to find out more about Prisma in detail is the documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs. Specifically, [this article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/introduction/what-is-prisma-apohpae9ju) shares a high-level overview of what Prisma is and does.

### What database is Prisma based on?

Prisma is not based on a specific database. Instead, you can use [Prisma Connectors](https://github.com/graphcool/prisma/issues/1751) to connect your database to the Prisma layer, to obtain a GraphQL API. Currently supported databases are MySQL and Postgres and connectors for [MongoDB](https://github.com/graphcool/prisma/issues/1643) and [Elastic Search](https://github.com/graphcool/prisma/issues/1665) are currently in development, and [more will follow](https://github.com/graphcool/prisma/issues/1751).

### prisma deploy

`prisma deploy` does not create a new database server. You can use `prisma deploy` to deploy a Prisma API to a Prisma Server, which is connected to a database (as mentioned above).

For quick development, free development Prisma servers are available in Prisma Cloud. They can be deployed to without setting up a Prisma server or database first.

I assume that you are deploying against this free development server. In this case, you have no direct access to the database.

### Accessing the Database

Depending on the underlying database, you can use tools like [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) (for MySQL), [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) (for PostgreSQL) etc.

You can also use the databrowser from Prisma Cloud to explore and interact with your data, independently from the underlying data store.